# Share application screen on same computer, Ubuntu

Tags: linux, python, gui

Dear all i wanna to share application screen in same operating system

explain why , i connected another screen on my pc  as joint screen and i wanna to share application work in the main screen instead to run another program what

like to duplicate application gui

i'm using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set up your dual screen to use mirroring:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html

> Mirror: the same content is shown on two displays, with the same resolution and orientation for both.